# Best way to use text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need use a lot of text in my app. Early I use server to get data. But now I need save text in my program. Much text have some fields: title, short subtitle, and full text. How can I save it the best way, in .plist? Like dictionary

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"myValue" forKey:@"myValue"];
        NSString *myValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"myValue"];

Comment: You can also use Localizable.strings. Create the string file and add texts inside with their keys. By doing so, you will be able to have localized version of all of your strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the only solution but you can take some reference from it.

For me, I will first pull all the data from the internet with `json` `web-services`, process them into `nsdictionary` or `nsarray` and store them into the sqlite by using FMDB.

You can take a look how to store and retrieve data with FMDB. https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Then I can keep re-use them by fetching these data from the sqlite.

---

If you don't need to fetch data from the server, you can just create and insert all the data into sqlite by https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

drag and link the sqlite file with your apps, and retrieve the data from it by using `FMDB`